# iOS Maps - Grid Overlay

Tags: ios, grid, maps, overlay

I'm looking for a way to overlay the iOS maps with a grid. The complete earth needs to be divided into squares. The location of the user doesn't effect the placement of the squares (In other words; the squares are always placed the same. On every iPhone, no matter where the user is).

I Looked into MKOverlay, but I've never used this so it's very new to me. Also, when zooming in/out should effect the overlay. It's very important that the squares are always covering the same area on the map (For example; A square should be 100mx100m in real world, when you zoom out, the square should cover the same 100x100).

Is there anybody that can point me in the right direction?

[image: grid_example]

Is it possible to draw the grid from een .xml? Example given; On .XML is holding all squares with their coordinates on the map. When the user loads the map, the 100 squares around the user are loaded.

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: I have the same question. Did you find a solution?